# searching a log in powershell

Tags: powershell, split, indexof, select-string

I'm trying to use powershell to search a log for a particular string - and then use a particular section of a line that has that string.

The log lines I'm interested in look something like this:

2019-02-25 11:51:37.394 field1=data|field2=data|field3=data|field4=data|field5=data

I can get returns of those lines just fine - but i then need to extract the data from one of those fields to use for another search.  I'm stuck there.  how do i extract the data from a particular "field" (fields seperated by | and the data seperated from fieldname by =)?

```
$dir = "path\to\workingdir"
$file = "logfilename"
$str2 = "eventType=59"

$out = (Get-Content $dir\$file | Select-String -Pattern $str2 |out-string)
```

I need to extract and use the data in field 3 for another search of the log.  Anything I've tried just seems to return everything that i get in $out.  I can't seem to get "split" or "indexof" to work properly (at all)....though I'm not even sure if that's what i should be trying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you have the string with the fields in it, you can use the `.Split()` method to grab the items. something like this ...

```
'field1=data1|field2=data2|field3=data3|field4=data4|field5=data5'.Split('|')[2].Split('=')[1]
```

... will give you this ...

```
data3
```

Comment: That makes me think I'm doing my original search wrong...$out returns ALL lines with my search, so when i try that split i get a numeric value (like a count?) instead of the data I want.  Do i need to put the original search into some sort of array or hash table and then cycle through that?

Comment: you need to get JUST that line for the split i used to work. there are other ways to get the result - regex can handle the entire block of text, for instance. however, that requires a good deal more info about what the blob of text will contain. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll want to separate your log message from the timestamp:

```
$line = '2019-02-25 11:51:37.394 field1=data|field2=data|field3=data|...'
$date, $time, $msg = $line.Split(' ', 3)
```

e.g. like this, when you're processing a logfile:

```
Get-Content "${dir}\${file}" | ForEach-Object {
    $date, $time, $msg = $_.Split(' ', 3)
    # ...
}
```

With the timestamp out of the way you can process just the message by splitting at the delimiters:

```
$msg.Split('|') | ForEach-Object {
    $name, $value = $_.Split('=', 2)
}
```

Depending on your actual use case you could use the above for turning the log message into a hashtable

```
$data = @{}
$msg.Split('|') | ForEach-Object {
    $name, $value = $_.Split('=', 2)
    $data[$name] = $value
}
```

and then use that hashtable for further processing, e.g.

```
if ($data['eventType'] -eq '59') {
    # do some
} else {
    # do other
}
```

Comment: thanks.  This is probably a bit more methodical than i need at the moment but cleaning up/separating the log will be handy in the future.  I ended up using the .split in Lee_Dailey's solution.